# Jest function not returning database query in the test, but yet adding to the actual database

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, knex.js

I can't get the Jest tesitng functions to return any data from the database calls, nor from using the supertest http request maker library.

```
describe('API calls', () => {
    it('testing jest', () => {
        expect(2).toBe(2);
    })

    it('get request /areacodes', async () => {
        const response = await db('areacodes').insert({areacode: 804, city: "Richmond", state: "VA"})
        console.log(response);
        const res = await db.select('*').from('areacodes');
        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    })
})
```

I'm expecting the database call in the testing function to return something.  but it isn't.  it does add data to the database however when testing with insomnia.

Comment: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 200
    Received: undefined

      21 |         console.log(response);
      22 |         const res = await db.select('*').from('areacodes');
    > 23 |         expect(res.status).toBe(200);
         |                            ^
      24 |     })
      25 | })
      26 | 

      at Object.toBe (_tests_/server.test.js:23:28)

Answer (score 0):

You may have some problem in the `select` call. I recommend you to use a `Promise.then.catch` block to try to find the error:

```
db('areacodes').insert({areacode: 804, city: 'Richmond', state: 'VA'}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    db.select('*').from('areacodes').then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Also, you should inspect the `res` object, maybe it is all working fine, but it simply doesn't have a `status` property.

I have read the knex.js documentation and I can't find that `status` anywhere, so probably that is what is wrong.

Comment: For some reaso,  I tried using the .then() syntax, and then went back to the async await syntax.  And now it's returning data from the database queries.
```
    it('get request /areacodes', async () => {
        try {
            const response = await db('areacodes').insert({areacode: 701, city: "Richmond", state: "VA"})
            console.log(response);
            const ac = await db.select('*').from('areacodes');
            console.log('select response', ac);
        }

        catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the database response with a `status` property? I have updated my answer.